# Make absolutely-positioned <div> fall below info windows on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2010-06-30_1304.png) should explain my problem:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2010-06-30_1304.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2010-06-30_1304.png)

I'm using version 3 of the Google Maps API (if relevant)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the z-index of the infoWindow by using the getZIndex() mthod and set the zIndex for your overlay at anything lower than that or you can explicitly set the zIndex of an info window using setZIndex() method and set the zIndex to something really high..

so ..

z = yourInfoWindow.getZIndex();
yourDivID.style.zIndex = z-1;

or ..

yourInfoWindow.setZIndex(666);

If you post the code or a link to your app I could help you further..